# Using Selenium to select a frame

Tags: python, selenium

So I'm trying to select a frame using selenium. I found many examples and similar questions on stackoverflow regarding this.

All of them pointed out that to select elements that are in a frame you first have to "move" to that frame and then get the element you want.
But I can't seem to get the frame that I want.

All the post I read said use:

```
driver.switch_to.frame("contentfrm") # Fetch by name, or
driver.switch_to.frame(1) # Fetch by index
```

So I tries all of them and no matter what I use I always get an error that says it cannot find the frame, `selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchFrameException: Message: Unable to locate frame: contentfrm`

The python code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()

driver.get("http://10.0.0.2/html/content1.asp")
driver.get("10.0.0.2")

elem = driver.find_element_by_name("Username")
elem.send_keys("admin")

elem = driver.find_element_by_name("Password")
elem.send_keys("admin2")

elem.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

# ----
driver.switch_to.default_content()
driver.switch_to.frame("contentfrm")
# elem = driver.find_element_by_id("m8")

# driver.quit()
```

The HTML code:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<title>Quick Start</title>
</head>

<frameset onload="load()" rows="0,*" frameborder="0" border="0" framespacing="0">
    <frame name="topFrame" scrolling="no" src="../main/refresh.asp" __idm_frm__="200"></frame>
    <frame name="contentfrm" id="contentfrm" __idm_frm__="201"></frame>
</frameset>

</html>
```

Note: The code works correctly up to where I have to select the frame.

Any idea why this is happening

Comment: that frame has no content are you sure you don't want the `topFrame`?

Comment: @Rafael It actually does have content. I just didn't include it otherwise there would be to much code. But the element that I am looking to get is located in that frame

Comment: try removing default content before `switch` statement and also give some wait time before finding the element
```
driver.switch_to.frame("contentfrm");
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector(" ")));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without the website in question it's hard to pinpoint what the problem is but I will take a few assumptions:

- Your frameset is doing some javascript on the function `load()` which may make the elements unavailable when you try to find them.
- <strike>The frame element you're getting has no `src` attribute so it will have no content</strike>
- Maybe the selection in the function `switchto.frame()` doesn't work the way you think it does.

To be safe it's better to wait for the element to be visible and then select it by xpath

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//frame[@name='contentfrm']"))
)
driver.switch_to.frame(element)
```

Answer (score 1):

As @Rafael said, it is better to use a different locator, and you should check what the on load() javascript is doing. However I would suggest using the id of the frame as the locator and not an xpath for the frame name.

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "contentfrm")))
driver.switch_to.frame(element)
```